# CoffeeScript instance variable

Tags: coffeescript, instance-variables

I'm learning CoffeeScript, and I've got one minor headache I haven't quite been able to figure out. If I create an object to do certain things, I occasionally need an instance variable for that object to be shared between methods. For instance, I'd like to do this:

```
testObject = 

  var message # <- Doesn't work in CoffeeScript.

  methodOne: ->
    message = "Foo!"

  methodTwo: ->
    alert message
```

However, you can't use `var` in CoffeeScript, and without that declaration `message` is only visible inside `methodOne`. So, how do you create an instance variable in an object in CoffeeScript?

---

**Update:** Fixed typo in my example so the methods are actually methods :)

Comment: BTW I'm aware that I could do `message = ""`, but I really just want the variable to be null so I can set behavior based on existence rather than a more complex check to see if it's not "blank" etc.

Comment: You can also set `message = null` which is what you want no?

Comment: When I try `message = null` I get `ParseError Unexpected 'TERMINATOR'`

Comment: Oh yea, like the correct answer mentioned, you were assigning `testObject` to an object  `=` and not a function `= ()->`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't like that. To quote the [language reference](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical_scope):

> Because you don't have direct access to the var keyword, it's impossible to shadow an outer variable on purpose, you may only refer to it. So be careful that you're not reusing the name of an external variable accidentally, if you're writing a deeply nested function.

However what you're trying to do wouldn't be possible in JS either, it would be equivalent to

```
testObject = {
    var message;
    methodOne: message = "Foo!",
    methodTwo: alert(message)
}
```

which isn't valid JS, as you can't declare a variable in an object like that; you need to use functions to define methods. For example in CoffeeScript:

```
testObject =
    message: ''
    methodOne: ->
        this.message = "Foo!"
    methodTwo: ->
        alert message
```

You can also use `@` as a shortcut for 'this.', i.e. `@message` instead of `this.message`.

Alternatively consider using CoffeeScript's [class syntax](http://coffeescript.org/#classes):

```
class testObject
    constructor: ->
        @message = ''

    methodOne: ->
        @message = "Foo!"

    methodTwo: ->
        alert @message
```

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to @Lauren's answer, what you wanted is basically the [module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript):

```
testObject = do ->

  message = null

  methodOne = ->
    message = "Foo!"

  methodTwo = ->
    alert message

  return {
    methodOne
    methodTwo
  }
```

Where `message` is a "private" variable only available to those methods.

Depending on the context you could also declare message before the object so that it's available to both methods (if executed in this context):

```
message = null

testObject = 
  methodOne: -> message = "Foo!"
  methodTwo: -> alert message
```

Comment: Correct, but your code is a bit buggy: `do` will simply create a closure, you therefore cannot define properties but should use vars instead (`methodOne = ->...` etc.) Also, the return statement should probably be `{methodOne:methodOne, methodTwo:methodTwo}`. Of course you could put your method definitions right into the return statement instead...

Comment: @JulianD. *copy&pasta* :) The return statement is using [destructuring assignment](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring).

Answer (score 1):

You can define the property with:

```
message: null
```

<s>But, you aren't currently defining methods -- you need `->` for that.</s>

Then, to refer to instance properties within the methods, prefix the property names with `@`.

```
testObject = 

  message: null

  methodOne: ->
    @message = "Foo!"

  methodTwo: ->
    alert @message
```

Comment: `->` is not required: see [my fixed version](http://coffeescript.org/#try:testObject%20%3D%20%0A%0A%20%20methodOne%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%40message%20%3D%20%22Foo!%22%0A%0A%20%20methodTwo%3A%0A%20%20%20%20alert%20%40message)

Comment: @KristofferSHansen your version isn't fixed; as you can see by pressing 'Run' on that page, it would show an alert dialog immediately, and that is probably not what Andrew is after, more likely he wants to defer its execution until that method is called.

Comment: @KristofferSHansen It is for function/methods. Without it, `methodTwo` is set to the result of calling `alert`, not a function that in turn calls `alert`.

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo, I fixed it. My real code had the `->`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@` to point to `this`

```
testObject = 

  methodOne: ->
    @message = "Foo!"

  methodTwo: ->
    alert @message
```

[fixed version on coffeescript.org](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3atestObject%20%3D%20%0A%0A%20%20methodOne%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%40message%20%3D%20%22Foo!%22%0A%0A%20%20methodTwo%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20alert%20%40message)